# SQLite select next closest date

Tags: java, sqlite, quartz-scheduler

I have a table which has the following columns:

```
ID | DATE | CRON | MAXIMO |FEATURES
int  date   text   text    varcahr
```

I am using this table to store data related to scheduled activities. I would like to grab the CRON string where the date is the closet next element to the current date time. Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you googled it? I can find questions similar to this one.

Comment: I have found similar questions, but they're not quite the same and the answers have not been as helpful as I would like them to be.

Comment: What is the format of the values in the `date` column?

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work for you. I'm not too familiar with sql-lite so I used oracle sql:

First use this sub-query to get all of the closest records for every ID:

```
select T1.ID, min(ABS(t1.date - t2.date)) date2
from TABLE_NAME t1,
TABLE_NAME t2
where t1.ID != t2.ID --don't look at the same row's of you'll get 0 every time.
--You'll have to play with the where clauses depending on what you're looking for.
--This would return the closest date regardless of the ID or other columns
group by T1.ID
;
```

Now you can use that sub-query in a regular query whenever you need to find the closest date:

```
SELECT TAB1.ID, SUB1.MinDate
FROM
(
select T1.ID, min(ABS(t1.date - t2.date)) MinDate
    from TABLE_NAME t1,
    TABLE_NAME t2
    where t1.ID != t2.ID  time.
    group by T1.ID
 ) SUB1,
    TABLE_NAME TAB1
    WHERE SUB1.ID = TAB1.ID
    ;
```

I think this should work for what you're asking for. You might need to modify the were clause but the logic is there.